# Missing argument for parameter #1 in call when using findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6.3

I am trying to get an array of PFObjects, `[PFObject]`, from Parse and seeing the issue below. What am I missing?

Error is **Missing argument for parameter #1 in call**

```
func loadData() {
    rooms = [PFObject]()
    users = [PFUser] ()

    self.tableView.reloadData()

    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "user1 = %@ OR user2 = %@", PFUser.currentUser()!, PFUser.currentUser()!)

    let roomQuery = PFQuery(className: "Rooms", predicate: pred)

    //gives us all the information - includeKey all columns for the user class itself
    roomQuery.includeKey("user1")
    roomQuery.includeKey("user2")

    roomQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget{ (results: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            self.rooms = results as [PFObject]

            for room in self.rooms {
                let user1 = room.objectForKey("user1") as PFUser
                let user2 = room.objectForKey("user2") as PFUser

                if user1.objectId != PFUser.currentUser() {
                    self.users.append(user1)
                }

                if user2.objectId != PFUser.currentUser() {
                    self.users.append(user2)
                }
            }
         self.tableView.reloadData()

        }


    }

}
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to handle the response with a block but you decided to use `findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget`. You should go with [findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:). So you should be having something like this:

```
roomQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```